# Opening Access Report from Excel goes to the 'save as' window

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, report

I want to open an Access report from Excel but instead of showing the report it goes to the 'save as' window.

I tried acViewDesign, acViewNormal, acViewPreview and without one as well but it all gives me the same thing.

```
Dim accessApp As Object


Sub DisplayReport()

Dim DocName As String
Dim Path As String

Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

Path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Database1.accdb"

accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase Path

accessApp.DoCmd.OpenReport "Sheet1", acViewReport
accessApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add reference to the the Access Object Library or use the value 5 in place of acViewReport

```
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenReport "Sheet1", 5
```

All the constant values are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acview)